# Flicking background image using Phonegap with Android

Tags: android, cordova, user-interface

I've got an application that uses PhoneGap and it has a brackground image. My issue is that, even though I'm using the source, the image flicks a little bit. (It seems that Android and PhoneGap are taking different references of the screen to display the image).

This is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.splash);

    this.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.setIntegerProperty("backgroundColor", Color.TRANSPARENT );                    
    cna = new CustomNativeAccess(this, appView);   

    appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                 appView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    appView.getSettings().setCacheMode(android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
    appView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    appView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash );          

    appView.clearCache(false);
    super.loadUrl(url); // this is an external url so it takes a bit of time
```

}

as a temporary fix I have force the app to work in full screen, and in that way doesn't do the flicking as both (Android and PhoneGap) take as reference top 0,0.

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

I'm using PhoneGap 1.6 and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Finally this problem got solved updating to PhoneGap 2.2, so it seems that it was a PhoneGap issue.